# cakephp to know the all set variable in controller itself

Tags: php, cakephp, methods

Can it be possible to track all the set variable by `$this->set('variable_name', 'some_value')`
in the controller's method itself.
Actually i have a method that call several other method and each sub method set the value to view. Now I am unable to track if the same key set twice in the main method or not.

example

```
    function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->set('key1', 'viable value');
}


function reqMethod()
{
    $this->extendMethod1();
    $this->extendMethod2();
    $this->extendMethod3();
    $this->extendMethod4();
    $this->extendMethod5();
    $this->extendMethod6();
            // Want to track all set variable (key) here.
}

private function extendMethod1()
{
    $this->set('key1', 'unknow value');
}
```

Here it may possible that key1 (by mistake) can be set to another method.
Any help really be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Controller::set() just adds value(s) to the 'viewVars' property, so to debug all those variables, you'll only have to do this:

```
debug($this->viewVars);
```

You could have discovered this yourself, by looking inside the source?

[view the source](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.1/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L834)

Comment: Thank you!! it helps to trace the mistake i did.  
Yeah I had to look it..but i missed this.

Comment: Can confirm that the same works on CakePHP 3 as well

Comment: Lots of things have changed in CakePHP 3, so it probably will be different, but it's been a while since I touched CakePHP after changing jobs

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to write it to a session. Eg. in beforeFilter ()

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->set('key1', 'viable value');
    $this->Session->write ('key1', true);
}

private function extendMethod1()
{
    $this->set('key1', 'unknow value');
    if ($this->Session->check('key1')
     {
        // whatever needs to be done.
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort